# Adding images with PHPExcel that have links

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, phpexcel

I've been searching around the web and haven't been able to find out if this is possible or not, or how to do it, so I ended up writing my question here.

I am creating an Excel file with PHPExcel, which is then zipped with a bunch of images and then served as a download for our users.

The thing is, we want to be able to put tiny thumbnails of the photos into the excel file and make the thumbnails have relative links to the original photos.

I know how to add a photo to excel files and I know how to add a hyperlink to a cell, but would it be possible to have several photos per cell and let each photo have their own relative link?

I've tried just doing it in Excel itself, which is possible, so it's just a matter of possibility with PHPExcel or if I need to find something else to do it, which would then require me to rewrite a lot of other code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found out by searching more around the web, that PHPExcel doesn't support adding hyperlinks to images.

I did find a Python library, which does so very nicely and will now be trying to call a python script from php instead. The library is called xlsxwriter and can be found here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/index.html#